# how to add 'postgres' - operating system user account? (Installation by source - suse 15.3/ postgres 15.2)

Tags: postgresql, user-accounts, suse

I'm on my way installing postgres 15.2 under Suse Linux Enterprise 15.3 by source, following the instructions from [www.postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org):

I'm stuck at chapter "19.2. Creating Database Cluster" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-user.html)

```
root# mkdir /usr/local/pgsql
root# chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql
root# su postgres
postgres$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

The postgres User (I'm looking for operating system user account") does not exist yet.

**My question: how can I add the new postgres- system operation user account (with right permissions for postgreSQL)?**

- Important to know for postgreSQL:
  "PostgreSQL user accounts are distinct from operating system user accounts" (vgl. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-createdb.html)
- referring to MAN-Page [text](https://www.unix.com/man-page/suse/8/useradd/) by default "the home directory will be created and the initial default files and directories will be copied."
- I don't need a home-directory
- I don't want to create the Database Cluster with my personal user-account
- referring rights, as far as I guess from pg-documentation, the new user only needs full rights on usr/local/pgsql (I'm not that sure about this point)

Comment: The page you linked to (which is apparently not the one you *thought* you were linking to) tells you what to do.

Comment: Nothing wrong with installing from source, but on suse/opensuse it's just bat .. bleep .. crazy.... I've used suse/opensuse since 7.0 Pro and currently have postgresql 15.3 happily running on Leap 15.4. The RPM install does the complete setup for you. As root just `zypper in postgresql15 postgresql15-contrib postgresql15-server` add `postgresql15-devel` if you want the C/C++ library and headers. (it may get pulled in anyway on a 'recommends' dependency) Just accept whatever the suggestions are. Works fine. Talks to Archlinux without a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page [postgres-user.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/postgres-user.html) mentions the required commands (`useradd` or `adduser`). Run `useradd --help` to see available options. They are also all mentioned in the referenced man page.

Maybe you are just confused by the text following `Depending on the command line options`. No home directory will be created unless `-m` is specified.

I think you are all set by just running `useradd postgres`.

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that I have used opensuse since SUSE Linux 9, it is pretty easy to install PosgreSQL.

You can also just install `postgresql` or `postgresql14` or `postgresql15` using Yast2's software manager (just search for postgresql and check the box--seriously, that is all you need to do to get started) or Zypper: (as root) zypper in postgresql (or the specific version).  You can get the latest by adding the  database repository  (from download.opensuse.org under http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/database/SLE_15_SP4/).

The install scripts creates the user/group, gives you a reasonable configuration, and creates a service you can start on boot or by hand using the Yast2 (gui) service module or `systemctl`.

You should then configure authentication/security and add users specific for your need.

Don't make it hard.

Comment: "*You should then configure authentication/security and add users specific for your need.*" How to do this is what OP is asking about, not how to install Postgres. See above: "**My question: how can I add the new postgres- system operation user account (with right permissions for postgreSQL)?**" This does not appear to answer that question.

Answer (score -1):

The following information might be useful for anyone else, the postgres- operation system user account is:

- in a group "postgres"
- the group has only one member, the user "postgres"
- the id is always "26"
- the home directory point to the path to the directory of "pgsql", e.g. /var/lib/pgsql/*version*/*data*
- is a system user/ belongs to the group of system user
- login disabled

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? It looks more like extraneous information.